# Information about controller.service_arguments

Tags: php, symfony

Can using the controller.service_arguments tag affect the operation of the page?

Website performance dropped a lot when I started using this tag.

Comment: The container, where the tag is used, is compiled once in production and therefore it should not have a noticeable impact. If you notice something in development it is far more likely that compiling the container is what you notice, which can happen for a multitude of reasons

Comment: What have you tried to check **why** the performance is worse than before?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

As @dbrumann noted, the tag is only used during compilation of the container, more precisely in the `RegisterControllerArgumentLocatorsPass`, so that controller classes can receive services as arguments via dependency injection, even if they do not extend from any base controller class (as noted in the default `config/services.yaml`).

In production, with a compiled container, this should not have any effect. In dev-mode however, it could increase the compilation time of the container, as  @dbrumann said, since it needs to resolve more arguments.

How do you want to use this tag precisely?